# Seaborn regression plot with different colors

Tags: python, regression, seaborn

I want to plot a linear regression model fit for my dataset using Seaborn.

As this data set has different depths in water column (Bottom, Middle and Top), I wanted my plot to have 3 different colors, but the linear regression would be to the overall dataset. I divided this dataset to plot them separately just like the following:

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True)
axarr[0].scatter(averageOBSB_3min,PumpBotSSC,c='r', label='Bottom')
axarr[0].scatter(averageOBSM_3min,PumpMidSSC,c='g', label='Middle')
axarr[0].scatter(averageOBST_3min,PumpTopSSC,c='b', label='Top')
```

But that doesn't work for Seaborn, obviously.

My question is: how can I have different colors on the plot, but do the regression for the hole dataset?

Answer (score 5):

Use mix of Seaborn's `lmplot` and `regplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns
#Use lmplot to plot scatter points
graph = sns.lmplot(x='x_value', y='y_value', hue='water_value', data=df, fit_reg=False)
#Use regplot to plot the regression line for the whole points
sns.regplot(x='x_value', y='y_value', data=df, scatter=False, ax=graph.axes[0, 0]))
```

Comment: Thank you. When I plot with lmplot the regression coefficients are shown, but using regplot they are not. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension to @O.Suleiman answer and your comment. Seaborn [`lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) nor [`regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) have a way how to directly annotate your fit with its parameters. For that you should check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902739/seaborn-annotate-the-linear-regression-equation). To sum up both the solutions and since you do not provide any data I used seaborn dataset, what you would use is:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats

# get coeffs of linear fit
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(tips['total_bill'],tips['tip'])

# Use lmplot to plot scatter points
sns.lmplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='smoker', data=tips, fit_reg=False, legend=False)

# Use regplot to plot the regression line and use line_kws to set line label for legend
ax = sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, scatter_kws={"zorder":-1},
line_kws={'label':"y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}".format(slope,intercept)})

# plot legend
ax.legend()
```

[image: pic]